# Increasing max_frame rate in amqp.js -- Hitting limits in buffer copy

Tags: node.js, amqp

I have a situation where I have about 50 listeners on 50 'direct' exchanges. The client and the server are in javascript (node.js) . It is using the node-amqp from postwait .
Things work fairly well at low frequency of messages. Once the message frequency increases ~ 5000 messages per minute then there is a buffer copy error being shown in amqp.js
From what I could trace the max_frame_size in amqp.js is fixed to **131072** .

I just tried to double the value from 128k to 256k . But doing so causes the node.js to silently fail without starting up. There is no error message. I am assuming that I also have to change the corresponding value (max_frame) in the rabbit.config file.

Do I have to do anything else to increase this value . Any other suggestions will also be appreciated.

I have attached the minimal code to simulate the error . Run the commands below in  2 windows to simulate the error

**node engine-so-client.js -c 200 -p 12000**

**node server-so.js**

File **server-so.js**

```
var util= require('util')
var amqp = require('amqp');
var express = require ('express')


function httpServer(exchange) {
   console.log("In httpServer start  %s",exchange.name);
   var port;
   app = express.createServer();

   app.get('/message/:routingKey/:message',function(req,res) {
    exchange.publish(req.params.routingKey,{'d' : req.params.message});
    res.send('Published the message '+req.params.message+'\n');
});

app.get('/register/:socket/:routingKey',function(req,res) {
    var queue1 = conn.queue('',
            {autoDelete: false, durable: true, exclusive: true},
            function() {
                    console.log("Queue1 Callback");
                    queue1.subscribe(
                    function(message) {
                            console.log("subscribe Callback for "+req.params.routingKey + " " + message.d);
                    });
                    console.log("Queue Callback Binding with "+req.params.routingKey);
                    queue1.bind(exchange.name,req.params.routingKey);
            });
    res.send('Started the socket at '+req.params.socket+'\n');
   });

   app.listen(3000);
   app.use(express.logger());
   console.log('Started server on port %s', app.address().port);
   }

   function setup() {
      console.log("Setup");
      var exchange = conn.exchange('cf2-demo',
    {'type': 'direct', durable: false}, function() {
    var queue = conn.queue('',
            {autoDelete: false, durable: true, exclusive: true},
            function() {
                    console.log("Queue Callback Binding with test key");
                    queue.bind(exchange.name,'testKey');
            });
                    queue.on('queueBindOk',
                            function() { httpServer(exchange); });
   });

   console.log("Completed setup %s", exchange.name);
   }
   var conn = amqp.createConnection({host:'localhost',
                                    login:'guest',
                                    password:'guest'},
                             {defaultExchangeName: "cf2-demo"});
   conn.on('ready',setup);
```

File **engine-so-client.js**

```
var program = require('commander.js');
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');

program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .option('-h, --host <host>', 'Host running server', String,'localhost')
    .option('-p, --port <port>', 'Port to open to connect messages on',Number,12000)
    .option('-k, --key <key>,',  'Routing Key to be used',String,'key1')
    .option('-c, --count <count>','Iteration count',Number,50)
    .option('-m, --mesg <mesg>','Message prefix',String,'hello')
    .option('-t, --timeout', 'Timeout in ms between message posts')
    .parse(process.argv);

function setup(host,port,key,mesg) {
  var client = http.createClient(3000, host);
  var request = client.request('GET','/register/'+port+"/"+key);
  request.end();
  request.on('response', function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    postMessage(host,port,key,mesg,1);
            });
  });
 }

 function postMessage(host,port,key,mesg,count) {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    var mesgNow = mesg+"-"+count+"-"+port;
    console.log("Type: Sent Mesg, Message: %s, Time: %s",mesgNow,timeNow);
    var client1 = http.createClient(3000, host);
    var request1 = client1.request('GET','/message/'+key+"/"+mesgNow);
    request1.end();
    count++;
    if (count <100) {
       setTimeout( function() { postMessage(host,port,key,mesg,count); }, 1000 );
    }
  }
  var port = program.port;
  var host = program.host;
  var key = program.key;
  var mesg = program.mesg;
  var count = program.count;
  var keys = ['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5'];
  var messages = ['hello','world','good','morning','bye'];
  var start=port;
  for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
      var index = i%keys.length;
      var socket = start + i;
      setup(host,socket,keys[index],messages[index]);
  }
```

Error attached

```
buffer.js:494
throw new Error('sourceEnd out of bounds');
      ^
Error: sourceEnd out of bounds
at Buffer.copy (buffer.js:494:11)
at frame (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:170:10)
at header (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:160:14)
at frameEnd (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:205:16)
at frame (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:172:14)
at header (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:160:14)
at frameEnd (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:205:16)
at frame (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:172:14)
at header (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:160:14)
at frameEnd (/home/hvram/programs/node_modules/node-amqp/amqp.js:205:16)
```

Comment: node 0.6.8 and amqp 0.1.1 are the versions I am running and on Ubuntu 11.04 . RabbitMQ 2.7.1

Comment: Whats the connection between server and client, is there any proxies or dreaded antivirus software running (e.g. NOD32?)

Comment: no there is no proxy . All software is running on the same machine

Comment: What exactly is the buffer copy error? Minimal code to reproduce?